# Incorrect ComCtl32.dll is loaded after porting a project from Win32 to x64 platform in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have ported a project from `Win32` to `x64` platform. I changed all dependencies so I can build the project smoothly. However, as soon I start the executable I'm getting an error `(0xc000007b)`.

Using the dependency walker I can see, that at a certain point the `ComCTL32.dll` is loaded but the `x86` and not the `x64` as expected.

As soon I turn of the manifest generation (`linker->Manifestfile`), it works. But that's not a solution.

So my question is: Where in `Visual Studio 2010` can I set the path to the correct DLL `ComCtl32.dll`.

Comment: Thx for the corrections Casey

Answer (score 8):

Well, the manifest matters.  An example of a bad one that could cause this problem would look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
            version="6.0.0.0"
            processorArchitecture="x86"
            publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
            language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
```

The processerArchitecture attribute value matters.  A good one uses `*`, which means *compatible* or `amd64`, which means *64-bit*.

Comment: Hi Hans, thank you point me to the my problem. I had the following line in my header: 
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

Answer (score 1):

You don't set the path anywhere. You specify a manifest to indicate which version of ComCtrl you want, and then it is up to the OS to find it, like any other DLL.  The error you are seeing means a 64bit process is trying to load a 32bit DLL, or vice versa.  That could be a search path issue, that could be a dependancy issue.  Use a tool like DependancyWalker to find the culprit.